# Laravel files not storing in storage directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm storing files in Laravel api. Files are mostly images. The images are storing at `public/storage/claim-images` but not in `storage/app/public/claim-images`. Isn't images supposed to stored in both directory ? Here is how I'm storing the files

```
return Storage::disk('public')->put('claim-images', $request->file('claim-image'));
```

Note that I alreday run the `php artisan storage:link`

*Laravel version - 7.30*

Comment: can you show filsystem.php code

Answer (score 0):

Read your `filesystem.php`. You are using the `public` disk in your code, this means that the path will be `public_path()` as seen in the configuration.

What you are looking for is to use the `'local'` disk, which should default to `storage_path('app')`. For all defaults, check the source on Github [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/filesystems.php).

`php artisan storage:link` is creating a Symlink IN the public folder TO de storage folder. So this is not working out for you since you are storing files directly in the public folder instead of the storage folder. The correct end result should be that all files reside in the storage folder, while the symlink in the public folder refers to that directory.

See for more info https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk